# which axis for coordinates in a list of points [NumPy]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

Say I have a list of `N` points each with `d` coordinates.  There is a choice of representing this as a `numpy` `array` of shape:
- `(d, N)`
- `(N, d)`
which are mathematically equivalent.

**Question.**  Are there general guidelines/good practise principles for choosing one over the other?  Computationally speaking, is `numpy` designed with one choice in mind?

**A interpretation in favour of `(N, d)`.**
If I were to store coordinates of a list of points in a spreadsheet, then I would find it more natural (or is it just me?) to go through the list vertically (downwards) and through the coordinates horizontally.  In other words, each row of the spread sheet corresponds to a Python `tuple` (fixed length, immutable), and the spreadsheet corresponds to a Python `list` of such `tuple`s.  The number of coordinates in the spreadsheet is fixed, but more points could be added (or removed) to the list, and thus the length of this list is unbounded, and I find it easier to scroll vertically than horizontally.

**Example.**
In the k-means clustering algorithm, one wants to calculate the distance between each of `N` points with each of `k` cluster centers (all of which have `d` coordinates).  From [this article](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/#clustering-algorithms) I am learning a way to do this by exploiting **broadcasting**.  If `X` is an array of shape `(N, d)` of sample points and `C` is an array of shape `(k, d)`, then the distance can be conveniently calculated by taking the element wise length of the array

```
X - C[:, None]
```

of shape `(k, N, d)`.
It would be less convenient to do this with arrays of shapes `(d, N)` and `(d, k)`, respectively.

Comment: I doubt there is any good practise about this, simply choose the one which suits you best and stick to it all along.

Comment: I have seen libraries use either convention, although I think `(N, d)` is more common.